# Is it possible to force SymPy to either compute an integral, or tell me why it cannot compute the integral?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm trying to compute the integral, specifically, the Laplace transform, of a piecewise function.

```
w_k = k*t, 0 <= t <= 1/k
      1,   otherwise
```

So I attempted to integrate it as follows:

```py
from sympy import *
t, k = symbols('t k', positive=True)
w_k = Piecewise((k*t, (0 <= t)&(t <= 1/k)), (1, True))

integrate(w_k * exp(-s*t), (t, 0, oo)).doit()
```

```
Out:
∞                         
⌠                         
⎮ ⎧     -s⋅t          1   
⎮ ⎪k⋅t⋅ℯ      for t ≤ ─   
⎮ ⎪                   k   
⎮ ⎨                     dt
⎮ ⎪   -s⋅t                
⎮ ⎪  ℯ        otherwise   
⎮ ⎩                       
⌡                         
0
```

Using `laplace_transform` gives me the same result.

I'm aware that sometimes certain conditions need to be fulfilled for the function to be possible to integrate by SymPy, but I'm really not sure what other than the positive variables is needed for this function. Is there any way to force SymPy to either compute the integral, or explain why it isn't possible?

Comment: If SymPy returns an unevaluated integral, the reason is that none of the algorithms are able to handle the integral. I'm not sure what sort of "reason" beyond this you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import math
from sympy import *
s = Symbol('s', positive=True)
t = Symbol('t', positive=True)
k = Symbol('k', positive=True)
function = Piecewise((k*t, (0 <= t)&(t <= 1/k)), (1, True))
result = integrate(function * exp(-s*t), (t, 0, math.inf))
```

Output:

```
k/s**2 + exp(-s/k)/s + (-k - s)*exp(-s/k)/s**2
```